# Visual Studio for Mac 2019 - Load failed : Invalid value for Link Property

Tags: macos, visual-studio, .net-core

After cloning my project from GitHub. On the very first time, Solution gets open and load all 5 projects. But after quitting VS, when I restart the same solution, then 3 out of 5 project unable to load and shows this error.

> Load failed : Invalid value for Link Property

Note - this solution work fine in VS 2019 for window. I am getting issue just in Mac.

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: We don't do *urgent* htelp here. No question is more urgent or important than any other. If you need urgent or immediate help, delete your question here and hire a contractor and pay them to provide that help. You've also provided no details that will allow anyone to help you at all. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages (especially [ask] and [mcve]) to learn how the site works and what our expectations are before you begin posting.

Comment: @KenWhite what else details you need ? I have already explained my issue.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue.
I was finally able to fix it by deleting the bin and obj folders before opening the solution.
The problem occurs again if with the solution closed I build or run the project from a console and then try to open the solution.
Hope the answer helps as the issue is still occurring in 2023 with Visual Studio version 17.5.

Answer (score 0):

Your Visual Studio complains about the content of its .csproj files, specifically about how Link properties are set inside.

Looking some more it seems that such error is thrown in the case if the file path starts with ".." or if it is absolute path : https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/blob/master/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects/ProjectFile.cs

Basically you will have to open .csproj files and fix those problems. If they are consistently made by Visual Studio you will have to submit the bug and wait for it to be fixed and possibly use some older version if it doesn't have such a problem.

Comment: firstly thanks for your pretty good explanation.
If it has issue of ".." then how VS manage to open it on the very first go ?
Actually problem start when I restart the solution.

Comment: @codeIam as said above it could be that Visual Studio is changing those paths.

Answer (score 0):

This does not necessarily have to do with the csproj itself but can be any file in that project. In my case it was a file within a folder called "i18ntext". I reported the issue to the Visual Studio Mac Team and they are investigating it:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1073405/invalid-value-for-link-property.html

For your issue: have a look at the ide log (you can open the log folder via the diagnostic menu). Maybe you find what this is causing. Also might be a good idea to follow the issue I created and report your issues in case it isn't resolved with my ticket.